# remove space between views in ViewFlipper

Tags: android, view, viewflipper

I am trying to make a slide animation with 3 views inside a ViewFlipper and when I switch among them I get a blank space. Is there any way to remove the space between the views when I try to change them in Action_Move so that it would look like they are stuck together?

here is the XML:

```
<ViewFlipper 
    android:id="@+id/ViewFlipper1"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:background="#000000">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#aabbcc"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#cfcfcf"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#adadad"/>

</ViewFlipper>
```

and here is the animation I am trying to make:

```
float firstTouchX = 0;
float leaveTouchX = 0;
float firstTouchX2 = 0;
float leaveTouchX2 = 0;
float oldMoveTouchX = 0;
ViewFlipper VF = null;

public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    VF =(ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper1);
       int eventaction=event.getAction();
       final View currentView = VF.getCurrentView();

       switch(eventaction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:               

           firstTouchX = event.getX();
           oldMoveTouchX = firstTouchX;

           break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        int deltaMovement = (int)(event.getX() - oldMoveTouchX);
        oldMoveTouchX = event.getX();


        if(deltaMovement < 0 ) 
        {                           
            currentView.layout((int)(currentView.getLeft()+deltaMovement),
                currentView.getTop(), (int)(currentView.getRight()+deltaMovement),
                currentView.getBottom());
        }
        else
        {
            currentView.layout((int)(currentView.getLeft()+deltaMovement),
                    currentView.getTop(), (int)(currentView.getRight()+deltaMovement),
                    currentView.getBottom());
        }
        break;


        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                leaveTouchX = event.getX();
          if (firstTouchX - 50 > leaveTouchX) {

            VF.setInAnimation(AnimationHelper.inFromRightAnimation());
            VF.setOutAnimation(AnimationHelper.outToLeftAnimation());
            VF.showNext();

          }
          else if (firstTouchX + 50 < leaveTouchX) {

            VF.setInAnimation(AnimationHelper.inFromLeftAnimation());
            VF.setOutAnimation(AnimationHelper.outToRightAnimation());
              VF.showPrevious();

          }
              break;


}
       return true;
}

public static class AnimationHelper {
      public static Animation inFromRightAnimation() {
        Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
        inFromRight.setDuration(500);
        return inFromRight;
      }

      public static Animation outToLeftAnimation() {
        Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
        outtoLeft.setDuration(500);
        return outtoLeft;
      }

      // for the next movement
      public static Animation inFromLeftAnimation() {
        Animation inFromLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
        inFromLeft.setDuration(500);
        return inFromLeft;
      }

      public static Animation outToRightAnimation() {
        Animation outtoRight = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
        outtoRight.setDuration(500);
        return outtoRight;
      }
    }
```

Comment: In case some don't understand, when I move view1 to the left I want view2 to come from the right and leave no space between them.

Answer (score 0):

In view flipper:-

android:layout_height="300dp"
     android:layout_width="300dp"

instead replace with

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Comment: that's not it, I want to remove the space between them when I scroll with ActionMove.